# Can't put View over chart

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to bring a custom `View` in front of a `SmoothLine`, but either the `Smoothline` is moving below the `View` or the `Smoothline` is - I'm not sure, but it seems to be like - overlapping the `View`.

I'm using `react-native-pathjs-charts` for generating the chart.

Here are the current code snippets and its results:

```
  <View style={styles.viewStyle}>
    <View style={styles.contentViewStyle}>
      <Text style={styles.bigNumberStyle}>2.202.122 €</Text>
      <Text style={styles.typeStyle}>UMSATZ</Text>
    </View>
    <SmoothLine data={data} options={options} xKey="x" yKey="y" />
  </View>
```

Leads to:
[image]
When I move the `View` inside the `Smoothline` as a child, the following happens:

```
 <View style={styles.viewStyle}>
        <SmoothLine data={data} options={options} xKey="x" yKey="y">
          <View style={styles.contentViewStyle}>
            <Text style={styles.bigNumberStyle}>2.202.122 €</Text>
            <Text style={styles.typeStyle}>UMSATZ</Text>
          </View>
        </SmoothLine>
      </View>
```

[image]

Is there any way to bring the `View` to front that it overlaps the chart?

PS: It would be nice if it was possible without `react-native-overlay`.

Comment: Have you tried old fashioned `position: absolute`?

Comment: @mjwatts It actually worked after setting the View's position property to `absolute` !

Comment: Ok I added my answer below with more detail if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding `position: 'absolute'` should work. See the [docs#position](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/layout-props.html#position) for more info.

**From the docs:**

`position` in React Native is similar to regular CSS, but everything is set to `relative` by default, so `absolute` positioning is always just relative to the parent.

If you want to position a child using specific numbers of logical pixels relative to its parent, set the child to have absolute position.

**Use absoluteFillObject:**

You could also use this handy shortcut I learnt from [Today I Learned](https://til.hashrocket.com/posts/202dfcb6c4-absolute-fill-component-in-react-native):

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  backgroundImage: {
    ...StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject,
  },
})
```

Instead of:

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  backgroundImage: {
    position: 'absolute',
    top: 0,
    right: 0,
    bottom: 0,
    left: 0,
  },
})
```